# setNeedsDisplay not working?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drawing, key-value-observing

I have a problem redrawing a custom view in simple cocoa application. Drawing is based on one parameter that is being changed by a simple NSSlider. However, although i implement -setParameter: and -parameter methods and bind slider's value to that parameter in interface builder i cannot seem to make a custom view to redraw itself.

The code that does redrawing is like this:

```
- (void)setParameter:(int)newParameter {
  parameter = newParamter;
  NSLog(@"Updated parameter: %d", parameter);
  [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

I DO get the message about setting the new parameter although the view doesn't redraw itself. Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual syntax is: `[self setNeedsDisplay:YES]`, although I would assume that that means the same thing. Are you implementing the `- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect` method, or using the `drawRect:` method of your superclass?

Comment: thanks for pointing out typo with true/YES

I implement my own drawRect: method

Comment: if you put an NSLog(@"hi") at the top of your DrawRect: method, does it get called?

Comment: no, it doesn't get called. it gets called only once on program startup

Comment: hmmm. Based on the information given so far, I'm stumped. Is there anything out of the ordinary about your setup?

Comment: does this thread help at all? http://www.idevgames.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-10114.html

Comment: well i worked it out in a different way.

i removed setter and getter methods and changed them with one IBAction in custom view class that updates instance variable and calls setNeedsDisplay. Works like a charm.

I guess i need more homework with KVC/KVO theory.

Thanks again, eJames!

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that has this problem while using an `NSOpenGLView` subclass, you might be forgetting to use `[[self openGLContext] flushBuffer]` at the end of `drawRect:`.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes reason can be very simple: File's owner has no connection to UIView object. i.e. it's Outlet is not setup properly. 
Use IB, ctrl button and drag method :)

Comment: This is a very good hint. In fact my view is NOT connected now although I´m sure my view was connected properly once. Now I got the problem that I can´t connect the view to the File's owner. Looks to me that something is broken.

Answer (score 0):

In the iOS 6 there isn't such function to call: `setNeedsDisplay:YES`. I've got the same problem, and came with this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15027374/1280800 .

Hope it will help.