# I want to redraw a view

Tags: iphone, view, redraw

I want to redraw a view.
When I touch a button, my view have to redraw itself. (have to call viewWillAppear)

But view's setNeedDisplay method doesn't redraw itself immediately.
Because I have to redraw it immediately, the method is not suitable to me.

I tried to remove all of viewController's view's subviews and to change viewController's
 view to other view.
But these didn't work. (don't redraw)

I need your help acutely.

Thank you for your reading.

Comment: [Rob Napier](http://stackoverflow.com/users/97337/rob-napier) answered a similar question, [what-is-the-most-robust-way-to-force-a-uiview-to-redraw](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503761/what-is-the-most-robust-way-to-force-a-uiview-to-redraw?tab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are some misunderstandings here. Let's set things straight:

1. `viewWillAppear:` has nothing to do with the drawing of the view.
2. It's true that `setNeedsDisplay` doesn't redraw the view instantly, but we're talking milliseconds. So that's not even relevant.

Since you want `viewWillAppear:` to be called I'm assuming that what you call redrawing the view really should be referred to as relayouting the view. I assume that what you do in `viewWillAppear:` is setting the frames of you're views and possibly add/remove and/or show/hide some views.

I suggest that you move that code out of `viewWillAppear:` and into it's own method that will be called from `viewWillAppear:` and when you tap the button.

Since you don't provide your `viewWillAppear:` code this is all based on assumptions, so if my assumptions are wrong, please let me know and please do provide your "redraw" code.

Answer (score 1):

Without more details it's hard to know exactly what you need but I might suggest you look at UIView::setNeedsDisplay.  This will in turn cause your views drawRect: to be called where you can update the drawing.

Comment: I misunderstood that setNeedDisplay will call viewWillApear. Now, I know that setNeedDisplay will call view's drawRect:. Thank you Ripred.

Answer (score 1):

```
[yourViewName setNeedsDisplay];
```