# Does setNeedsDisplay have immediate effect or it is merely queued for later?

Tags: ios, uiview, drawrect, setneedsdisplay

Does anybody here know whether `setNeedsDisplay` results in an immediate `drawRect` call and immediate updating of the screen?
Or is it merely a queued request?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The view is not actually redrawn until the next drawing cycle.  This simply notifies the system that the view should be redrawn.

See [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)

You can apparently accomplish this by setting the content mode to `UIViewContentModeRedraw`.  I haven't done this personally, but the code should be something along the lines of

```
UIView *redrawView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
...
redrawView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
```

See [View and Window Modes: Content Modes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW2)

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can force a redraw to happen immediately? Thanks.

Comment: setting the contentMode to UIViewContentModeRedraw doesn't in my tests cause an immediate redraw after setNeedsDisplay, only when the bounds change. so I suppose you could jigger the bounds?

Comment: You might also look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503761/what-is-the-most-robust-way-to-force-a-uiview-to-redraw