# SetNeedsDisplay with monotouch

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I am trying to create a custom ProgressBar with MonoTouch. I created a class which redraws a line with a timer. My issue is that when the`SetNeedsDisplay` is called the view doesn't redraw itself. Only when a touch is provided does the `SetNeedsDisplay` call the OnDraw method. What do I have to do so that the `OnDraw` method gets called without a touch?

Comment: are you calling SetNeedsDisplay in the correct thread? If you call it in the timer-thread, it will not be drawn (look at the not accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503761/what-is-the-most-robust-way-to-force-a-uiview-to-redraw))

Comment: you just saved me from a lot of time my friend. Just type as an answer that I have to call the main thread (InvokeOnMainThread) so that I can reward you.

Comment: Just wrote an short answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure to call `SetNeedsDisplay` in the ui-thread, otherwise it will not redraw the view. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503761/what-is-the-most-robust-way-to-force-a-uiview-to-redraw)