# How to resize notification center widget's height in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, widget, height, ios-app-extension

I am developing a widget on iphone. I want to resize height of widget.
I changed it as follows. but I didnt find a refresh mechanism. It works after reopen NC panel.

```
-(void) updateView {
    CGRect widgetRect = _view.frame;
    widgetRect.size.height = widgetHeight;
    _view.frame = widgetRect;
}
```

Do you have any idea?
Regards,
Bliss

Answer (score 0):

-- this should do it for you.

```
[myView setNeedsDisplay]
```

See this link:[What is the most robust way to force a UIView to redraw?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503761/what-is-the-most-robust-way-to-force-a-uiview-to-redraw)

Comment: I tried this before. Widget's height doesnt change. Notification Center controller doesnt take last _view and doesnt refresh widget's height. I need a trick to get last _views to all widgets or mine.

Comment: What do you mean "last" views? Are all the views on the page or are you deallocting them? If you don't deallocate them they should be accessible at all times.