# subClassed NSView not appearing in a Custom View

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, subclass, nsview

I have subclassed `NSView` and I added it to another view like this:

```
clockT = [[CustomView alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 156, 155)]; 
[holderView addSubview:clockT];   
[clockT setNeedsDisplay:YES];
clockT.tZone = @"Canada/Yukon";
```

The view was created and added to `holderView` but not visible. It is visible during resizing the Window. **Note:** I am using a transparent Window.

Comment: Your view might need a layer...

Comment: show more of HolderView and of customView... what did you override / whats your init or drawRect

Comment: also pay heed to naming: Don't start variable names with a capital letter

Comment: what is the frame on your container view. you might be getting clipped

Comment: i created a container view for the width of customView. Initially i displayed only one customView. If the user clicks a button then increases the customView width and container view width. But the CustomView was not shown untill any user interations occured in window.

Comment: I hope you are invoking the above code in main thread. setNeedsDisplay does not have any effect from background thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you are using transparent view, It was not visible to others. Create the window with full size and create your objects and display instead to increasing holderview width.

Answer (score 2):

There is a sample application on the [Apple Developer Site](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/RoundTransparentWindow/Introduction/Intro.html) that may help you with that. This sample demonstrates how to create windows with custom shapes, no title bar, and transparent content.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing more code, it is hard to tell what's going on. This thread has some advice that might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1503828/171933

Could it be that you are not calling this from the main thread? Does your view have a custom `drawRect:` implementation? Could you put a breakpoint there to see what size the passed-in rect has? Is it the right size?

What if you just create a vanilla NSView with, say, a green background color and add that to your holder view? Does that work? If so, something is wrong with the implementation of your `CustomView`.

Without seeing more code it is hard to pinpoint the problem.