# Is [NSWindow setFrame:display:] API asynchronous?

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

I have a strange UI behavior which made me think that this API might be asynchronous. Assuming it is (async), I've made some changes and now the UI works as expected. I didn't find the answer in Apple's documentation. 
Is anyone familiar or had some experience with this? Is it really async? Thanks!

EDIT: All UI changes are being made from the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

`setFrame:display:` updates the frame and tells the system to redraw the window (and possibly the subviews) during its next drawing cycle. Cocoa drawing is always done during its drawing cycle, not at the moment you call a drawing method. See [What is the most robust way to force a UIView to redraw?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503761/what-is-the-most-robust-way-to-force-a-uiview-to-redraw/1503828#1503828) for some more discussion on that.

This is better thought of as drawing being "consolidated" rather than "asynchronous." Unless there are animations, all drawing should generally be complete before the next event loop. It's possible that a view will somehow delay its drawing to a later event loop, but rare. Layer-backed views in 10.8+ can support actual async drawing, but this is not the default.

From you description, it's possible you're calling `setFrame:display:` from a thread other than the main thread. AppKit drawing is not thread safe. You cannot call drawing methods from anywhere but the main thread, or you'll get "strange UI behavior." (This isn't completely true. On OS X, you can use `lockFocus` to draw from other threads, but they still won't actually be applied until the next drawing cycle after you unlock focus. But normally it's best just to draw from the main thread in modern OS X since GCD makes this simple.)

Comment: Being more specific about the 'strange' behavior, when doing Z-ordering immediately after `setFrame:display:`, sometimes Z-Ordering is not being executed. What do you mean by "drawing cycle"?

Comment: The drawing cycle happens at the end of the event loop. There's some method of yours that Cocoa called (`drawRect:`, a timer event, whatever). Drawing isn't going to occur until you return from that function at least. `setFrame:display:` shouldn't modify z-ordering, so I don't know what you mean by "being executed."